# Using make to install a library

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have a library that I would like to use make to install:

```
// library = foo

$ ls foo/
lib include

$ ls foo/lib
foo.h

$ ls foo/include
foo-1.2.a foo-1.2.o foo-1.2.etc

// makefile

.PHONY: install-foo
foo=/path/to/unzipped/foo
current_dir=$(shell pwd)
install-foo:
    - cd $(foo); ./configure --prefix=$(current_dir); make; make install
```

The above will always install

```
//makefile 2
.PHONY: install-foo reinstall-foo

foo=/path/to/foo
curdir=$(shell pwd)

install-foo: $(curdir)/foo/lib/foo.h $(curdir)/foo/include/foo-1.2.a etc.

$(curdir)/foo/lib/foo.h:
    make reinstall-foo

$(curdir)/foo/include/foo-1.2.a:
    make reinstall-foo

... (etc)


reinstall-foo:
    cd $(foo); ./configure --prefix=$(curdir)/foo; make; make install
```

And this one will install once for each file in the library, but (after that), it will reinstall when one of the files is missing.

Finally, I have a bash approach that is only so-so, as it does it with bash rather than make:

```
// within install-foo:
    -(not ((-f $(curdir)/foo/foo.h) and (-f $(curdir)/include/foo-1.2.a) and (etc.)) && really-install-foo

really-install-foo:
    ...etc.
```

The question is: what is a makefile design that will install the first time once, and any subsequent calls to `make install-foo` will cause `foo` to be installed only if one, more, or all of the library files are missing?

Comment: You are storing your header files in a subdirectory named `lib` and your binaries in a subdirectory named `include`? Is this on purpose?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet what? you are on here, answering my question, and you have never installed a gnu library locally from a tarball? For instance `wget .../gmp/gmp-whatever.tar.gz; tar -xf ...etc...; ./configure --prefix='/my/gmp'; make; make install` and it outputs in this structure.  Not only that, all the libraries unpack as a `lib/header` and `include/binaries`

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I mean, I would understand you answering the question, but to sneer, in ignorance? as if **I chose** that structure? It's appalling.